# Why does the cdc_ether driver not working correctly?

Tags: networking, 16.04, ethernet

I am using a USB modem Hilink E3531 to reach network in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. But when I enable networking and try to connect the Hilink through USB, it shows me this message:

[image]

So I disconnected and reconnected it from USB 3 or 4 times, then it works correctly until it disconnects automatically and this time even I repeat the process of disconnect-reconnect,  it does not work and if I try the command `ifconfig`, it shows me that the Hilink is still there and it is connected but I can't use network.

*Note: Some information about the computer:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be a little late for your needs - anyway for what it is worth:

I don't have a complete answer, but have met this issue myself and can provide at least some more information:

I think the USB dongle you're referring to is similar to the Huawei E3372h (currently / until recently the "standard" basic 4G dongle available in the UK in 'O2' and 'EE' stores).    This is a very good dongle, presenting through USB as a 'micro router' - presents (when EE) as 192.168.8.1 and (when O2) 192.168.3.1 - and provides DHCP service to the the device it's plugged into (e.g. under O2 leases it 192.168.3.10).

All of that, ALWAYS works fine for me on both types of dongle variant / cellular service.  BUT - the cdc_ether  driver,   SOMETIMES gives us trouble on some machines (we are makers of Linux-based industrial products) in that it simply fails to instruct the dongle to connect to the cellular network.

Only thing I can tell you for sure is that Lubuntu running 4.4.0-97 Kernel works fine with the dongle, while Ubuntu Server on a slightly older machine running  4.4.0-91,  the cdc_ether  driver fails to connect the dongle to the cellular network (but the IP interface to the dongle works normally).

I've just recently checked driver versions:

On the machine that works fine, I have

```
/lib/modules/4.4.0-97-generic/kernel/drivers/net/usb/cdc_ether.ko 
CRC (crc32) : ad1f4195
```

- 24,334 bytes,   19th September 2017

By comparison the one that fails,  is

```
/lib/modules/4.4.0-91-generic/kernel/drivers/net/usb/cdc_ether.ko   
CRC:  7d3cbf08
```

- 24334 bytes dated Aug  8 14:59

So not clear what's changed but a younger version (albeit on a different distribution) does work.  I've not bottomed the differences by updating drivers yet - recent issue for us also.

I hope this helps someone.

PS:
To list installed drivers use:

```
cat /proc/modules
```

To see ALL available drivers (Kernel modules) and where they are, use:

```
ls -R /lib/modules/\`uname -r\`/kernel/
```